# How do I make AFIncrementalStore post data to Rails as objects?

Tags: afnetworking, afincrementalstore

I have an iOS + Rails 3.1 app, and I'm using **AFIncrementalStore** for the client-server communication. It's a sort of calendar app, and `Activity` is the main model.

When I create a new *Activity* using a Rails web form, the server receives this:

```
Started POST "/activities" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-21 22:38:04 +0200
  Processing by ActivitiesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"pruaVLfUijjNrYfh17yJmQgYLrnrA713OjgdayudZAg=", "activity"=>{"text"=>"Test från web", "starts_at_formatted"=>"23:00"}, "commit"=>"Create Activity"}
```

But when I post from my iOS app, it looks like this:

```
Started POST "/activities" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-21 22:36:10 +0200
  Processing by ActivitiesController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"activityID"=>"0", "auth_token"=>"xkT2eqqdoNp5y4vQy7xA", "ends_at"=>nil, "starts_at"=>"2013-06-21T22:36:10+0200", "text"=>"Inserted!", "updated_at"=>nil}
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
```

I.e. I'm missing the `"activity"=> {...}` bit that wraps the *Activity* data. How do I achieve this, do I need to do a massive overhaul of `representationOfAttributes` in my `AFRESTClient <AFIncrementalStoreHTTPClient>` subclass?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `-representationOfAttributes:ofManagedObject:` in your `AFRestClient` subclass to wrap the dictionary returned by default.

If the default attribute mapping is already working, it's probably as simple as this:

```
- (NSDictionary *)representationOfAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes ofManagedObject:(NSManagedObject *)managedObject
{
    return @{[managedObject.entity.name lowercaseString]: [super representationOfAttributes:attributes ofManagedObject:managedObject]};
}
```

If you need to do some custom attribute mapping, just do that in place of my call to `super`.